# SQL - Updating rows based on reference data in lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, tbl_english, containing the column "word".
I also have a table, tbl_translation, containing the columns "german_word" and "english_word".

tbl_translation is supposed to be a lookup table to see if there are any german words in tbl_english' column "word"

So what I want to do is;

> For each tbl_english.word,  iterate through
>   tbl_translation.german_word and look for matching value.      If match
>   exists, update tbl_english.word with the value in
>   tbl_translation.english_word from  current row in tbl_translation

The intention is to replace any rogue german words existing in tbl_english with their correct translation from the lookup table tbl_translation

So far what I have come up with is this;

```
UPDATE tbl_english SET word = 
    (SELECT english_word FROM tbl_translation 
        WHERE tbl_english.word = german_word) 
    WHERE word IN
        (SELECT german_word FROM tbl_translation
            WHERE tbl_english.word = german_word )
```

However, this fails when there are multiple instances of the same or different words resulting from the first sub-select. Is there a simple way to solve the problem?

Example:

tbl_english contains;
Mädchen
Frau
Boy
Giraffe
Baum

tbl_translation contains (german, english);
Mädchen, Female
Frau, Female

So in tbl_english I would like to see the following result;
Female
Female
Boy
Giraffe
Baum

Edit: Not every word in tbl_english will have a reference row in the translation table. 
Edit2: Added example

Comment: Maybe you should show an example. If an english word can have multiple german equivalents, you need to define which one you want, and perhaps you could show how to identify a "rogue" word. Is it just one that doesn't exist at all in tbl_translation? What if it is there but is a translation of a different English word?

Comment: Please assume that multiple unique German words can be translated into one English word. One unique German word will never have more than one translation.

Also, the only way to identify a 'rogue' word is if it exists in tbl_translation

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense. If a word in tbl_english doesn't have a row in tbl_translation, which german word do you pick? The funniest one? Please show some sample data.

Comment: If there is no word match in the reference table, then you would not pick any word. I will however post an example =]

Comment: So what do you want the english word to become if there isn't a match? Again, pulling teeth from word problems IS NOT FUN.

Comment: As specified in the example, nothing. Assume that this system is not perfect, it merely wants to adhere to a reference table.

Comment: So my query does exactly that. It ignores rows where the english_word aren't in the translation table, and updates those that are. Did you try it before complaining about the assumptions it made?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I misread it and discredited it. You solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE e
  SET word = t.english_word
  FROM dbo.tbl_english AS e
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_translation AS t
  ON e.word = t.german_word
  WHERE e.word <> t.english_word;
```

Comment: That assumes that each english word also lives in the translation table. Unfortunately it's not so. My bad for not specifying in the original post. Will edit. Appreciate the input though.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If the english word isn't in the translation table, then how do you pick which german word to use? Roulette wheel? Draw a card?

Comment: This is a problem metaphor =] I realize it's not an air tight one; however, please go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try use aliases for sub tables?

```
UPDATE tbl_english SET word = 
(SELECT TOP 1 t.english_word FROM tbl_translation t WHERE tbl_english.word = t.german_word) 
WHERE word IN
(SELECT TOP 1 t.german_word FROM tbl_translation t WHERE tbl_english.word = t.german_word)
```

I hope i didnt misunderstand your question.

Comment: I thought of that, but that would add the same value each time. There might be 1 instance of rogue german words, or there may be 100s of unique ones. This would not cover the latter scenario.